# Can a second thread enter the same critical section just because the first thread called Monitor.Wait using the same sync lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Please tell me if I am thinking it alright.

1. A different thread cannot enter *the same critical section* using
   *the same lock* just because the first thread called `Monitor.Wait`, right? The `Wait` method only allows a different thread to acquire
   *the same monitor*, i.e. *the same synchronization lock* but *only for a different critical section and never for the same critical
   section*.

   Is my understanding correct?

   Because if the `Wait` method meant that anyone can now enter *this
   same critical section using this same lock*, then that would defeat
   the whole purpose of synchronization, right?

   So, in the code below (written in notepad, so please forgive any
   typos), `ThreadProc2` can only use `syncLock` to enter the code in
   `ThreadProc2` and not in `ThreadProc1` while the a previous thread
   that held and subsequently relinquished the lock was executing
   `ThreadProc1`, right?
2. Two or more threads can use *the same synchronization lock* to run
   different pieces of code at the same time, right? Same question as
   above, basically, but just confirming for the sake of symmetry with
   point 3 below.
3. Two or more threads can use *a different synchronization lock* to
   run the same piece of code, i.e. to enter the same critical section.

Boilerplate text to correct the formatting.

```
class Foo
{
    private static object syncLock = new object();

    public void ThreadProc1()
    {
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(syncLock);

            Monitor.Wait(syncLock);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Monitor.IsLocked(syncLock))
            {
                Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ThreadProc2()
    {
        bool acquired = false;

        try
        {
            // Calling TryEnter instead of
            // Enter just for the sake of variety
            Monitor.TryEnter(syncLock, ref acquired);

            if (acquired)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Monitor.Pulse(syncLock);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (acquired)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

The following illustration confirms that #3 is correct although I don't think it will be a nice thing to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DifferentSyncLockSameCriticalSection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sathyaish = new Person { Name = "Sathyaish Chakravarthy" };
            var superman = new Person { Name = "Superman" };
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            // Must not lock on string so I am using
            // an object of the Person class as a lock
            tasks.Add(Task.Run( () => { Proc1(sathyaish); } ));
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { Proc1(superman); }));

            Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Proc1(object state)
        {
            // Although this would be a very bad practice
            lock(state)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine((state.ToString()).Length);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a thread calls `Monitor.Wait` it is suspended and the lock released. This will allow another thread to acquire the lock, update some state, and then call `Monitor.Pulse` in order to communicate to other threads that something has happened. You must have acquired the lock in order to call `Pulse`. Before `Monitor.Wait` returns the framework will reacquire the lock for the thread that called `Wait`.

In order for two threads to communicate with each other they need to use the same synchronization primitive. In your example you've used a monitor, but you usually need to combine this with some kind of test that the `Wait` returned in response to a `Pulse`. This is because it is technically possible to `Wait` to return even if `Pulse` wasn't called (although this doesn't happen in practice).

It's also worth remembering that a call to `Pulse` isn't "sticky", so if nobody is waiting on the monitor then `Pulse` does nothing and a subsequent call to `Wait` will miss the fact that `Pulse` was called. This is another reason why you tend to record the fact that something has been done before calling `Pulse` (see the example below).

It's perfectly valid for two different threads to use the same lock to run different bits of code - in fact this is the typical use-case. For example, one thread acquires the lock to write some data and another thread acquires the lock to read the data. However, it's important to realize that they don't run at the same time. The act of acquiring the lock prevents another thread from acquiring the same lock, so any thread attempting to acquire the lock when it is already locked will block until the other thread releases the lock.

In point 3 you ask:

> Two or more threads can use a different synchronization lock to run
>   the same piece of code, i.e. to enter the same critical section.

However, if two threads are using different locks then they are not entering the same critical section. The critical section is denoted by the lock that protects it - if they're different locks then they are different sections that just happen to access some common data within the section. You should avoid doing this as it can lead to some difficult to debug data race conditions.

Your code is a bit over-complicated for what you're trying to accomplish. For example, let's say we've got 2 threads, and one will signal when there is data available for another to process:

```
    class Foo
    {
        private readonly object syncLock = new object();
        private bool dataAvailable = false;

        public void ThreadProc1()
        {
            lock(syncLock)
            {
                while(!dataAvailable)
                {
                    // Release the lock and suspend
                    Monitor.Wait(syncLock);
                }

                // Now process the data
            }
        }

        public void ThreadProc2()
        {
            LoadData();

            lock(syncLock)
            {
                dataAvailable = true;
                Monitor.Pulse(syncLock);
            }
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            // Gets some data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Beautiful, that `dataAvailable` hedge to ensure that the monitor was pulsed. Thank you. There are a few new thoughts that I now have reading your answer but I will ask them in a different comment below. First, could you please also confirm my understanding in the original question, esp. #2 (which is the same as #1) and #3?

Comment: Meanwhile, nice pictures on Flickr. I am also interested but in video / making films. I have a YouTube channel but I am not very good yet.  :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - I've updated the answer (and thanks for looking at the pictures!)

Comment: As to your answer for point #3, I thought the same thing too because it was more intuitive to think that two threads cannot acquire different locks to enter the same critical section. But the wording on the MSDN documentation led me to believe so. Here are a few statements from the documentation that confuse me. Verbatim: *"While it is possible for the Enter and Exit statements that lock and release a given object to cross member or class boundaries or both, this practice is not recommended."* I am searching for yet another one that was more clear in what it said.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 this last sentence just means you should avoid doing Enter in one method and then doing Exit in another method, or even in another class, because it's too easy then to forget to release the lock which will block all other threads trying to enter the same section, forever. So good practice is to do Enter\Exit in the same method (or even better just use lock statement which does the same).

Comment: @Evk Thanks. I see. This statement, though, was not the *real* one that confused me. This one was a bit ambiguous, though, and you cleared it up for me. I am searching for one statement that spoke in a very direct tone, something to the effect, "unless another thread entered the same critical section using a different lock." I am trying to find that one in the MSDN. I will post it as soon as I do.

Comment: @Evk and Sean: Here I found the prescription. In no uncertain terms, it is declared, "Thou shalt not covet thy neighbour's wife...UNLESS...unless another thread uses a different lock to enter the same critical section. Here it is verbatim, *"You can also use the Monitor class to ensure that no other thread is allowed to access a section of application code being executed by the lock owner, unless the other thread is executing the code using a different locked object."* and here is the source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx

Comment: @Sean And thank you for the wonderfully detailed answer, and esp. for clarifying point #1 and #2. That confirms my understanding regarding those two points. I do understand that the two threads that have acquired the same lock (or even different ones) do not run concurrently. And hence the cooperative notification system that `Pulse` and `Wait` constitute. And that concurrency, in truth, is an illusion, at least so far as single-core machines go.

Comment: @Sean and Evk: I guess #3 could be possible, although highly reckless, if the threads locked on some kind of state that the caller passed to them and that they were to use. I have updated my question to illustrate #3 and thus answer it. In summary, my assumption #3 is also correct.

Comment: @Sean When you get a chance, could you please edit that paragraph in your answer that contradicts #3?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 sure if multiple threads lock on different objects - they can execute the same code without any troubles. You could have illustrated that even with simple lock (new object()).

Comment: @Evk *>You could have illustrated that even with simple lock (new object())*. Oh yes! :-)